# ReFS to NTFS - How to reclaim space on drive?

Tags: windows, ntfs, refs, hdd

Physical 8TB HDD was formatted as ReFS with 64k Allocation Unit Size by mistake. Drive now shows it has 1.3TB of space instead of 8TB. If I format back to NTFS, it still shows only 1.3TB of space.

There is no data on the drive, so data loss is not a concern.

How can I undo this and reclaim all that lost space?

Comment: check the partiontable -> diskmgmt.msc is your friend at all ;-)

Comment: @djdomi I cannot see any other partitions on the drive in diskmgmt. Even if I delete the volume, there is only 1.3TB free space.

Comment: open `cmd` as admin and type `diskpart`  and show the output if `list disk` by editing your question, moreover you may join me shortly on [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150736/chatchat)

Comment: @djdomi So, I connected the drive to a different PC and was able to properly see what was going on via diskmgmt.msc. I have no idea why it was not displaying properly on the 1st PC. But I was able to resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: than please add an answer to the question and accept it 24h later - you may also do this with diskmgmt.msc from the menu, where you can reload the partions or using diskpart rescan iirc ;-)

Comment: @djdomi Yea, I tried all that but nothing was working. Something very odd was going on there on the original PC. I tried refresh, rescan disks, etc. I could not see the unused space in the other partition as I could on the 2nd PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I connected the drive to a different PC and was able to properly see what was going on via diskmgmt.msc. I have no idea why it was not displaying properly on the 1st PC. But I was able to resolve it.